# minimizing dfa in python

Tags: python, minimize, dfa

i am trying to find an algorithm for minimizing DFA in python. i have found some examples and they all have classes in code. Now, I do not know how to forward definitions of DFA which are placed in .txt file and put them in those classes. .txt is formated on following way:

1. line: The set of states separated by a comma, lexicographically ordered
2. line: A set of alphabet symbols separated by commas, lexicographically ordered
3. line: The set of acceptable states separated by a comma, lexicographically ordered
4. line: The first state
5. and all other lines: Transfer function in the format current state,Alphabet symbol->Next state

**example of definitions:**

```
dyny,fllf,gdci,gwtj,knos,kole,mjnw,msdl,mtfz,nbat,njgb,nzwx,rzpn,vcsc,zgfx

b,d,e,f,g,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,t,u,w

dyny,njgb,zgfx

mtfz

dyny,b->rzpn

dyny,d->msdl

dyny,e->gdci
.
.
.
```

**example of class**

```
class DFA:

    def __init__(self, states, alphabet, delta, start, accepts):
        self.states = states
        self.start = start
        self.delta = delta
        self.accepts = accepts
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.current_state = start
```

I load .txt file with

```
f = open('definition.txt','r')

lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried to so far? I am assuming this is your homework.

Comment: yes, something similar to homework. I have dfa class, and methods for printing, validating, deleting unreachable states... but i dont konw how to fill data in the class and its methods...

Comment: I don't know how to do your homework for you either ;) However if you give us more information then we can assist you.

Comment: only thing i want to know is how can I forward data I have in my .txt file to class and its methods

Comment: @skywlk: What do you mean by "forward". Parsing and calling the constructor?

Comment: @NiklasB: yes, I think so. If I got class-es aright that would be the easiest way to work with data I have stored in my .txt

Comment: You can walk through the file using `for line in f:`, then convert the enumeration lines using `set(line.split(','))` and the transition lines as `from, rest = line.split(','); symbol, to = rest.split('->')`

Comment: thanks for that, but is it possible to save that splited data in method in example? concrete: to save _dyny,fllf,gdci,gwtj,knos_ to _self.states = states_

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You could create a variable `states = []` and then use `states.append('dyny')` to end up with a list of states (`['dyny', 'fllf', ...]`). You can then pass that `states` variable to the constructor of `DFA`.

Comment: It seems you were not exposed to programming before. Due to the fact that you got this assignment your teacher/prof. thinks it's time. Take a day or two to learn a programming language. There are a lot of very good introductions to python. After that, a lot will seem very straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

So far, this has nothing to do with minimazation of automata, right? You are trying to create an automaton from some (given) file format.

Since this is a homework, I'll just give you some hints:

`readlines` returns a list. You can address specific lines by index, i.e., `lines[0]` for the first line, `lines[1]`, for the second, etc.
Each of these lines will be a string. Taking, for instance, the line containing the set of states (`lines[0]`, which holds `'dyny,fllf,gdci,gwtj,knos,kole,mjnw,msdl,mtfz,nbat,njgb,nzwx,rzpn,vcsc,zgfx'`), you can use

`lines[0].split(',')`

to split it by comma, which gives you a list of strings, each of which represents a state. Those lines which represent individual transitions follow a slightly more complicated format:

`<state>','<input symbol>'->'<next state>`

You want to parse those lines so that you get the three components depicted above. `string.split` is again your friend here. You should also decide on a suitable datastructure for the transition function (delta).

Note: `readlines` reads the entire file at once. In practice, automata are often quite big in which case it would be better to read the file incrementally. File objects (`f` in your code) implement the iterator protocol and allow you to iterate over the file's lines. In particular, I would suggest to use

```
line1 = f.next()  # Next line (first line, if first call of next)
line2 = f.next()  # Next line
...
```

for the first four lines (to get the set of states, etc) and to iterate over the rest (the transitions):

```
for line in f:
    ...
```

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html for details.

Comment: thanks for this. Yes, my idea is first to create automaton from given file, and then minimize it. Is it good way or should I skip this step?

Comment: No, it's OK to do it like that. But you should probably change the title of your question to something more appropriate.